How to store the time offset given in a timestamptz literal?
I need to store the the given time zone in the column (operation_time_zone):
INSERT INTO segments (
    operation_type, operation_time, operation_time_zone, operation_place, 
    passenger_name, passenger_surname, passenger_patronymic, 
    doc_type, doc_number, birthdate, gender, passenger_type, 
    ticket_number, ticket_type, airline_code, flight_num, 
    depart_place, depart_datetime, arrive_place, arrive_datetime, 
    pnr_id, serial_number) 
VALUES (
    $1, 
    ($2 AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::TIMESTAMP,
    (EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM $2::TIMESTAMPTZ) / 3600)::SMALLINT,
    $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21
);

But passed this way I get 0 in operation_time_zone.
Value $2 is '2022-01-01T03:25:00+03:00'. If I execute this query:
SELECT (EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM '2022-01-01T03:25:00+03:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ) / 3600)::SMALLINT AS timezone_in_hours;

I get 3.


What is the TimeZone set in the server?  2) What client are you using to run the query? 3) select 1000/3600; 0. Postgres does integer division unless you coerce one of the values to a non-integer type select 1000/3600.0; 0.27777777777777777778.


@AdrianKlaver 1) GMT +3 hours 2)github.com/jackc/pgx/v4 for golang

What is the value when you do show timezone;?

$1 etc implies you are injecting data directly from your client code, which is a really bad idea. How are you actually passing the parameters into the SQL statement?

@Charlieface , i passed this way
_, err := tx.ExecContext(ctx, query,
segment.OperationType, segment.OperationTime, segment.OperationPlace,
segment.PassengerName, segment.PassengerSurname, segment.PassengerPatronymic,
segment.DocType, segment.DocNumber, segment.Birthdate, segment.Gender,
segment.PassengerType, segment.TicketNumber, segment.TicketType,
segment.AirlineCode, segment.FlightNum, segment.DepartPlace,
segment.DepartDatetime, segment.ArrivePlace, segment.ArriveDatetime,
segment.PNRID, i+1,
)
query  is my upper code.
tx is a transaction. Golang.

Perhaps , it is because of wrong time parsing
e.g.
tm , _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04Z07:00","2022-01-01T03:25+03:00"),
i get "2022-01-01 03:25:00 +0300 +0300" with two timezones

Explanation
This expression only reflects the timezone setting of your current session:
EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM $2::TIMESTAMPTZ)

If you get 0, your session runs on UTC time (or a related time zone with no offset to Greenwich at the given time).
If you get 3, your session is set to a timezone somewhere near Russia - Turkey - Arabia - East-Africa. It only happens to coincide with the offset in the literal '2022-01-01T03:25:00+03:00'.
fiddle
Postgres timestamp data types do not store any time zone information at all - neither timestamp with time zone (timestamptz) nor timestamp without time zone (timestamp). The display of a timestamptz value is adjusted to the timezone setting of the current session, i.e. EXTRACT always sees the same offset.
See:

Time zone storage in data type "timestamp with time zone"
Ignoring time zones for Postgres timestamps

Solution
To preserve the time offset given in a timestamptz literal, pass $2 as text, and either parse the text representation (which is very tricky!) or, rather, use this expression:
   $2::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - $2::timestamptz

$2::timestamp casts the timestamptz literal to timestamp, ignoring the time offset (which is typically a sneaky mistake, but intended this time). Subtracting a properly cast timestamptz produces the effective time offset in the literal. This is cheaper than string processing and works for time zone names or abbreviations, too. Consider this comprehensive demo:
fiddle
Your INSERT could work like this:
INSERT INTO segments (
   ...
 , operation_time
 , operation_time_zone
 , ...
   )
VALUES (
   ...
 , $2::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
 , EXTRACT(hour FROM $2::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - $2::timestamptz)::int2
 , ...
   )

I also simplified to extract hours directly. Your integer division would truncate to the hour anyway.
